# How to find the pixel coordinate of difference from the output image got from background subtraction

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, background-subtraction

I have two input images, i have subtracted tow images using background subtraction.
How to get the exact coordinates of the difference on the output image?
this is the code i m using from geekseek

sub = cv2.subtract(image1, image2)

For e.g
[background subtraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRd21.png)

how to get the coordinates of Red marked box which is the output of the background subtraction.

Comment: `cv2.boundingRect` on the mask (bottom right image) will give you `x, y, w, h` of the box with `(x, y)` being the upper left corner and width `w` and height `h`.

Comment: Actually that bounding boxes has not drawn through code  , i have drawn it manually to show,? if i dont have the bounding boxes drawn then how to get the coordinates of the difference of the image ?

Comment: But you do have the mask (BOTTOM right image), right? The window is called `Thresh`. `cv2.boundingRect` on that image, and you're done.

Comment: ok, i will try this